# How to implement "Use one-click single sign-on" correctly in order to publish to Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

We already have a web app that integrate with differente Google services. Right now, you can loguin using a Google account, can import a contact lists from any Google account, and can sync a Google Calendar with our Calendar in the webapp (We implemented all of this using OAuth 2 and invoking the GoogleApi with a REST Client).

We are now trying to publish this app in the GoogleApp  Marketplace, but we are failing to comply with the "Use one-click single sign-on" rule (https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/practices#5_use_one-click_single_sign-on).

We are believing that the problem is we the way we are solving the fact that we need offline access for all the integrated users in the app. Right now, the only way we found to get the refresh tokens for them, was starting the OAuth2 process with the parameters access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force, but this forces them to enter their credentials.

We aren't using the 'Google+ Domains API', and we are starting to believe that we should. Is the use of this API mandatory for complying with the "Use one-click single sign-on" rule?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we finally figured it out. We had to use the Google Admin SDK in order to implement SSO. We had some troubles with the scopes, but after we polished that, everything seems to be working OK.